# Counting number of files in a directory with an OSX terminal command

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I'm looking for a specific directory file count that returns a number. I would type it into the terminal and it can give me the specified directory's file count.

I've already tried echo `find "'directory' | wc -l"` but that didn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea. I'd use `-type f` to find only files:

```
$ find some_directory -type f | wc -l
```

If you only want files directly under this directory and not to search recursively through subdirectories, you could add the `-maxdepth` flag:

```
$ find some_directory -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: The comment itself worked good, thanks. But Im a bit confused. I tested it with a NodeJs modules folder with a bunch of subdirectories. When I copied this folder Mojave told me there are (rounded) 75k files while `find some_directory -type f | wc -l` told me there are (rounded) 66k. How can this be possible?

Comment: @phng I'm guessing that Mojave also counts subfolders as files, whereas this `find` command limits it to actual files.

Comment: To anyone visiting in the future, you can also use -mindepth 1 if you don't want to count some_directory itself.

Answer (score 30):

Open the terminal and switch to the location of the directory.

Type in:

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

This searches inside the current directory (that's what the . stands for) for all files, and counts them.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand why folks are using 'find' because for me it's a lot easier to just pipe in 'ls' like so:

ls *.png | wc -l

to find the number of png images in the current directory.

Comment: But OP is not located in the images directory, they need a way to find the directory in addition to counting the images. That's why they use `find` and not `ls`. Otherwise, sure, you have a point.

Comment: That’s not what the subject line indicates.  It’s specifically to count files within a directory.  I’ve made the assumption that the reader understands file paths, directories and the ‘cd’ command.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to obtain the number of files within a directory is by obtaining the value of that directory's `kMDItemFSNodeCount` metadata attribute.

```
mdls -name kMDItemFSNodeCount directory_name -raw|xargs
```

The above command has a **major advantage** over `find . -type f | wc -l` in that it returns the count almost instantly, even for directories which contain millions of files.

Please note that the command obtains the number of [files](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_164), not just [regular files](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_323).

Comment: Note that this only works for the files directly in directory_name - it is not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually tree command is good alternative for find command.

1. Install tree

   ```
   brew install tree
   ```
2. Run command

   ```
   tree -R -L 99
   ```

   or

   ```
   tree -R -L 99 -a
   ```

   where:

- -R option to run recursively in folders
- -L specify level of the dir tree
- -a to show all files, included hidden

3. Scroll up to check which files have been counted.

PS. Remove autogenerated 00Tree.html in all nested folders

```
find . -name \00Tree.html -type f -delete
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using tree, this is the way :
tree ph

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 'tree' is not an OSX terminal command.